# Deploying nodejs on IIS server 2016 and getting error : 500

Tags: node.js, iis, web-deployment

I am deploying nodejs on IIS server 2016 and getting this error while hitting a path

```
(node:15707) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
```

In the meanwhile I only have one component and I am not using any buffer. here is the code:

```
var request = require('request');

  module.exports.maccAddress = async function (req, res){
    
  }

  module.exports.userLogin = async function (req, res){ 
    console.log(req.body.headers) 
    let jsonIn = 'jsonIn='+JSON.stringify(req.body.ipark_in) 



request({
    headers: req.body.headers,
    uri: req.body.url,
    body: jsonIn,
    method: 'POST'
  }, function (err, body) {
    if(err){
      console.log(body)
      res.send(err);
    }else{
      res.send(body) 
    }        
  });
```

}

Comment: If you used buffer() in code, replace it with Buffer.alloc(number) and Buffer.from(string). If you didnot use, please search all of dependencies and replace Buffer() with mentioned above.

Comment: {
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  }
}

Comment: Here is my dependencies, I didn't found any buffer

Comment: You can run grep -nrE '[^a-zA-Z](Slow)?Buffer\s*\(' --exclude-dir node_modules to find all the potentially unsafe places in code and replace Buffer(). And it seems that your node.js is 1.0? It has dropped support for Node.js<4.4. You can refer to [this](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/buffer-constructor-deprecation/) for different solution.